# Combine heatmap and slider - how to update the heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to make a heatmap update when a slider moves. The slider is supposed to set a date. When I move the slider, everything works as intended, yet the new heatmap is drawn in the slider's place and the slider disappears along with the first heatmap.

```
# Create the heatmap corresponding to a given date
def animate(date):
    global heatmapAx
    
    # reset plot area
    heatmapAx.clear()
    
    # query date related data
    flushdf = df2.query('DateYear == @date')
    
    # create heatmap-format matrix
    cross = standardizeCrosstab(pd.crosstab(flushdf["RetentionCostQuant"], flushdf["AssessedValueQuant"]), retention_bin_labels)
    cross.sort_index()
    
    # plot heatmap
    heatmapAx = sns.heatmap(cross, annot=True, fmt=".0f",  cbar=False, xticklabels=assessed_bin_labels, yticklabels=retention_bin_labels)
    
    # set heatmap title
    heatmapAx.set_title(date)
    return heatmapAx


# initialize matplotlib figure
fig, heatmapAx = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))

# adjust the subplots region to leave some space for the sliders and buttons
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)

# pick a first date
date_init = 2002

# generate a first heatmap with date_init
heatmapAx  = animate(str(date_init))

# generate slider with initial value
my_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.125, 0.1, 0.78, 0.03])
my_slider = Slider(my_slider_ax, 'Year', 2002, 2022, valinit=date_init, valstep = 1)

# link slider_action function to slider object
my_slider.on_changed(slider_action)

def slider_action(val):
    # the figure is updated when the slider is changed
    g = animate(str(val))
```

Here is the first plot, which is as intended, and with the slider at the right place

[image]

And here is what happens when I move the slider
[image]

What can I do to avoid this? I'm sure there's something I didn't understand but I can't figure out what.

Comment: I don’t know if this will resolve the issue, but if you’re running this in a notebook type environment, then you need to switch to interactive plotting. I don’t think this will work as an inline plot.

Comment: thanks @TrentonMcKinney, it didn't work but I tried